# Can I stop xcodebuild launching the simulator when no UI tests are run?

Tags: xcode, fastlane

I am using fastlane and the `scan` action to run tests. The UI tests are not run, but the xcodebuild still tries to launch the simulator it looks like (based on the output and the 1m 15s it takes between the warning and the tests actually starting to run.

Is there a way to tell fastlane (or xcodebuild) to not launch the simulator at all? I tried setting `devices: []`, but that just defaults to `iPhone SE 3rd gen`.

```
...
[12:32:00]: $ set -o pipefail &&
              env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild -scheme App\ \(QA\) -project ./Foo.xcodeproj -derivedDataPath ./build -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=E5D55B60-75B6-4AFC-9372-8E9485D5B1C4' -resultBundlePath './fastlane/UnitTests/App (QA).xcresult' -skip-testing:FooUITests test-without-building | tee '/Users/andrei/Library/Logs/scan/Foo-App (QA).log' | xcpretty  --report html --output '/Users/andrei/code/foo-ios/fastlane/UnitTests/report.html' --report junit --output '/var/folders/n9/8px5_dxj7ml7qschtrlgn96c0000gn/T/junit_report20230620-74099-c5ai6m' 
[12:32:00]: ▸ Loading...
[12:32:00]: ▸ 2023-06-20 12:32:00.702 xcodebuild[74164:4859085] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
[12:32:02]: ▸ --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
[12:32:02]: ▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5D55B60-75B6-4AFC-9372-8E9485D5B1C4, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro Max }
[12:32:02]: ▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5D55B60-75B6-4AFC-9372-8E9485D5B1C4, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro Max }
[12:33:17]: ▸ All tests
...
```